# How can i read tcp/udp header in application layer without using raw sockets?

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

Is there any "Api or system calls" to get whole packet from network layer without cutting the headers?

Answer (score -1):

You can't, unless your un-named operating system provides it via the `recvmsg()` function, which I believe Linux can do. Otherwise your question embodies a contradiction in terms.